# How to refresh a page whenever my js data file changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I've got this local file named 'data.js' containing various data.

```js
  var json={ 
  'city': 'madrid',
  'zip':'21212',
  'street':'bergstrasse',
  'house':'15',

};
for(key in json)
{
  if(json.hasOwnProperty(key))
    $('input[name='+key+']').val(json[key]);

}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="options.php" method="post" >

<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="stadt" >  
<br>
<input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="zip" >  
<br>
<input type="text" name="street" placeholder="straße" >  
<br>
<input type="text" name="house" placeholder="hausnummer" >  
<br>
<input type="submit" value="speichern" name="saves"></input>


</form>

   <script src="data.js"></script>
```

I want to refresh my page only when some data in the js file changes. Appreciate your help if you can explain me with bit of code. I searched all over internet, I couldnt find appropriate answer.

Comment: Step 1: separate data and logic. Step 2: actually "get" the data file (with `jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.ajax()`. Step 3: Compare the received data against your previous data and decide what to do with it (discard / update page).

Comment: @mpf82 is totally right, the best way is probably to make an AJAX call in a loop like setInterval(), then compare the new datas vs old ones and if it is different, update the div containing datas (but not the entire page imho).
You can use a redraw() function to preset the changes of the HTML content of the data-div element, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down.  You want to:

- check something periodically
- the thing you want to check is a remote file
- IF it has changed you want to take an action

As mentioned in the comments, there are ways to do all of the above in Javascript.

First let's address checking something periodically: you can either use a recursive `setTimeout` loop, or `setInterval`:

```
function waitOneSecond = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        check(); // will get to this in a second
        waitOneSecond();
    }, 1000); // 1000 = one second
});

function checkEverySecond() {
    setInterval(function() {
        check();
    }, 1000); // 1000 = one second
```

Next, we need a way to check whether the file changed.  The actual "did it change part" is up to you (you might want to consider using a function like Underscore or Lodash's `_.isEqual` for it), but to do that you'll need to get the latest version of the JSON file.  Luckily jQuery has a method for doing exactly that: `getJSON`:

```
function check() {
    $.getJson('http://yourserver.com/data.js').done(function(json) {
        if (didChange(json)) {// use _.isEqual to write your didChange
            takeAction();
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see this last example also covers taking action, but again I'll leave the definition of the `takeAction` function to you.